# Python, cx_Freeze "python setup.py build" doesn't do anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, exe, cx-freeze

I have made a game in pygame, and I want to show it to my friends, because they don't have python on their computer I have to convert my ".py" files in to ".exe", I watched some tutorials on Youtube about how to use cx_freeze(for compiling pygame scripts), but when i try the command "python setup.py build" in the command prompt, the only output I get i is `running build` and `running build_exe`, no errors, nothing more.

When I search in the folder where my "setup.py" and my game files are no "build" floder has been created.

I have tried to search about this issue but I haven't found anything, I would be grateful for some help.

sidenote: I am currently using anaconda python 3.6.5 for windows 64 bit and my cx_Freeze version is 5.1.1 also for windows 64 bit.

Comment: A dozen things could be going wrong. I recommend trying out [`pyinstaller`](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) if you can't get `cx_Freeze` to work.

Comment: I do know pyinstaller, it's really great but the only issue I have with it, it's that I can't compile multiple files at once.

Comment: What do you mean with "compile multiple files at once"? Isn't the `--onefile` option what you're looking for then?